# how to nest Azure function app (how to call another function app)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-synapse

So I have an Azure function app that has a timer trigger. It runs everyday in the morning at 4 Am. All it does is just execute a SQL Stored procedure from a Azure Data Warehouse.

The problem is: The stored procedure takes almost 20 - 25 minutes to complete. The stored procedure has several tasks that includes calling multiple stored procedures in it to move data from Azure data lake to SQL Data warehouse. when the stored procedure takes more than 20 minutes, the execution of the function app is not logged.

To better explain, if i go to the monitor page of the function app, some days logs are missing. so it's very hard to tell if the function app ran successfully or failed.

to avoid this, we planned to split the stored procedures tasks, but the problem here is, each stored procedure inside that parent procedure has a dependency on the sequence. The sequence is very important as there are data dependency in the underlying data.

i tried to look into the Durable Functions in Azure, but would need some expert to advice on this on how to utilize this.

So, can i create a new function app with some trigger that can be triggered after the parent function app or the stored procedure in it is complete ?

Please advice.

Comment: Side note -- if you're missing logs in Application Insights, make sure you've disabled sampling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#configure-sampling

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution you are looking for would be Durable Azure functions

[image: Azure Function chaining pattern]
[image: Fan out Fan In]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, there are two quick options:

1. [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/)
   As far as I'm concerned the best solution by far. This services feels like it would fit your scenario like a glove.
2. Have one function to run one SP
   In short: trigger Function 1 with the timer, run the first stored procedure and put a message on a queue as soon as the SP is done. The message on the queue [triggers the next Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) to execute the next SP. All the way untill all your SP's are done.

Comment: I would add two more services you could look into for this kind of task: durable functions and logic apps. Durable functions are made exactly for orchestrating functions. Logic apps are made for connecting to external data sources and moving the data into Azure.